# How to skip a package version?

Tags: apt

How can I be informed when a new version of a specific package is available for install? Is there a way to have apt-get skip a specific version, but install when the next one is available?

I am running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3, and have determined that the current version of a particular package breaks my set up. I reverted to a backed up image and then used `apt-mark hold` to prevent that package from being updated as I continue to `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to maintain all other packages on the device.

I see that `apt-cache show` gives me specific version information about the package that I put on hold, but I can't tell if it is giving me information on the version that is already installed or the version that is available to be installed, but not yet installed.  How can I see what version is installed and what is available to be installed?

Aside from getting this information, ideally, is there a way for apt-mark to only hold a specific version, but allow the next one to go? (I'm assuming that my issue will be resolved in the next version.)

Note, I have specifically not mentioned what package I'm having a problem with because I'm not trying (in this question) to troubleshoot that specific issue, but rather learn tools to manage similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so using *package pinning*. Create a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`:

```
Package: package-name
Pin: version 1:2.3.4.5-6
Pin-Priority: 450
```

This will set the priority of a particular package version below 500 (which AFAIK is the default value), so that this particular version will not be installed unless no other version is available. A future version will have the default priority and should be picked up during updates.

As you have already found out, `apt-cache policy package-name` will tell you which package versions are available. It will also display the priorities you have set by pinning.

Answer (score 1):

I've found `apt-cache policy [package name]` to give me the version number of the currently installed version and the version number of the version available to install.

Not a complete answer to my question, but a simple, convenient way to get the information I was looking for.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.